# Get user IP - Drupal website behind load balancers

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, load-balancing

Is there any work around for getting the actual **User IP** if the Drupal (7.17) website is behind load balancer? 
It always return me the IP address of load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want the `X-Forwarded-For` header, but the naive approach is wrong because [`X-Forwarded-For` can contain multiple IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), representing proxies en route.

Here's what you actually want ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/T0Bljh)):

```
<?php
// Don't use this function directly to parse arbitrary headers, since it
// assumes that the headers you're passing in are associated with the
// current $_SERVER variable.
function get_client($headers) {
    if (isset($headers['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        return explode(', ', $headers['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])[0];
    }
    else {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}

// You'd want to do this on a server, but not on ideone:
// $headers = getallheaders();
$headers = array('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => 'client, proxy1, proxy2');
echo "Client 1: " . get_client($headers) . "\n";

$headers = array('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => 'client');
echo "Client 2: " . get_client($headers) . "\n";

// $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is blank on ideone but works on servers:
$headers = array();
echo "Client 3: " . get_client($headers) . "\n";
?>
```

Also note that `X-Forwarded-For` can be easily spoofed, so you shouldn't rely on it exclusively in security contexts. The correct approach for e.g. a ban list would also require being aware of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has function  [ip_address()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/ip_address/7)

```
function ip_address() {
 $ip_address = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);

 if (!isset($ip_address)) {
   $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

     if (variable_get('reverse_proxy', 0)) {
       $reverse_proxy_header = variable_get('reverse_proxy_header', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

       if (!empty($_SERVER[$reverse_proxy_header])) {
         // If an array of known reverse proxy IPs is provided, then trust
         // the XFF header if request really comes from one of them.
         $reverse_proxy_addresses = variable_get('reverse_proxy_addresses', array());

         // Turn XFF header into an array.
         $forwarded = explode(',', $_SERVER[$reverse_proxy_header]);

         // Trim the forwarded IPs; they may have been delimited by commas and spaces.
         $forwarded = array_map('trim', $forwarded);

         // Tack direct client IP onto end of forwarded array.
         $forwarded[] = $ip_address;

         // Eliminate all trusted IPs.
         $untrusted = array_diff($forwarded, $reverse_proxy_addresses);

         // The right-most IP is the most specific we can trust.
         $ip_address = array_pop($untrusted);
       }
     }
   }

 return $ip_address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the IP using PHP, like that:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) {
    $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
else {
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```